# Install 'rgeos' package in R4.3.2

Tags: r, rgeo-shapefile

I am trying to install 'rgeos' package in R4.3.2, but i got this error (Error in install.packages : object 'rgeos' not found). any ideas?

install rgeos' package in R4.3.2. This Package ‘rgeos’ was removed from the CRAN repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rgeos` has been deprecated: see [here](https://r-spatial.org/r/2022/04/12/evolution.html) for discussion. If you really need `rgeos`, you can probably use `remotes::install_version("rgeos", version = "0.6-4")`, but (1) you will need development tools (2) you may need to figure out how to install GEOS (an external library) on your system ... an old version of the DESCRIPTION file says

> GEOS (>= 3.2.0); for building from source: GEOS from http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/; GEOS OSX frameworks built by William Kyngesburye at http://www.kyngchaos.com/ may be used for source installs on OSX.

The GEOS web site is [here](https://libgeos.org/).

If this is for more than a one-off "get some old code running one more time", it may be wise to follow the first link to figure out how to update your code.